# I have one background image which is responsive. but two images over the background image are not responsive. How to make those images responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have one background image which is responsive. but two images over the background image are not responsive. How to make those images responsive?

My background image is working fine when I resize the window it is responsive. but two images which are placed on background image are not responding when I resize the window. How to make both foreground images responsive?

CSS code:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
}

.Icon1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 77%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 130px;
}
    
.Icon2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 84%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 130px;   
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-no-padding wrapper">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="background1.jpg"
    alt="Responsive Image1" width="700" height="auto"/>

    <a href="https://www.google.com/"><img src="Images1.png" 
    class="Icon1" alt="Responsive Image" width="auto" height="auto"/></a>

    <a href="https://www.google.com/"><img src="Image2.png"
    class="Icon2" alt="Responsive Image" width="\auto" height="auto"/></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you going to add media queries?

Comment: What do you want to happen when the viewport is made smaller?

Answer (score 0):

Use `vw` instead of  `px` when you want to make some elements width according to screen width, [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) is more about css units.

Here's an example of your code using `vw`,

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    
    }
    .Icon1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 77%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 20vw;
    }
    
    .Icon2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 84%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 20vw;
    
    }

.img-responsive{
  width:100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-no-padding wrapper">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placekitten.com/640/360" alt="Responsive Image1"  />
  <a href="https://www.google.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/640/360" class="Icon1" alt="Responsive Image"/></a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/"><img src="https://placekitten.com/640/360" class="Icon2" alt="Responsive Image" /></a>
</div>
```